# Python: how to automatically repeat with different image input

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-rekognition

Below is a simple script for Amazon Rekognition.
AWS Rekognition is good at detecting image labels but supports taking only **one image per request.**
That means I have to change the name of the image file (in this case 'hot_air_baloon.jpg') every single time while I want to run quite a lot of images.

Is there a way to automatically repeat the request for every image in the folder?

```
response = client.detect_labels(
Image={
'S3Object': {
'Bucket': 'test1',
'Name': 'hot_air_baloon.jpg'
}}
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use a list which contains the names of all of your images and of course you should use a list to record all of your responses , for example
list=['hot_air_baloon.jpg','hello.jpg','image.jpg']
and then loop over it, this will be the correct code if I understood well your question:

```
responselist=[]
list=['hot_air_baloon.jpg','hello.jpg','image.jpg'] 
for image in list :
    response = client.detect_labels(
    Image={
    'S3Object': {
    'Bucket': 'test1',
    'Name': image
    }}
    )
    responselist.append(response)
```